Extract HKQuantity objects from HKQuantitySample
I am trying to compute personal records based of some running workouts fetched from HealthKit, as well as using distanceWalkingRunning samples.
I noticed that some running workouts has hundreds of HKQuantitySamples of few meters while others has only few HKQuantitySamples (like maybe 10 samples) of hundreds of meters and when I checked all distanceWalkingRunning manually in Health App on iPhone (Browse->Activity->Walking + Running Distance), I saw that these 10 big HKQuantitySamples has hundreds of small samples and I wonder how can I extract these small samples from the big ones.
In the apple documentation it says that "A quantity sample contains one or more HKQuantity objects."
So I guess I have to extract HKQuantity type objects from every HKQuantitySample object.
HKQuantitySample has a property count and I can use it to get it's number of HKQuantity, but I don't know how the extract all the `HKQuantity' objects..
Please correct me if I'm wrong with this analysis.
Any idea on how can I achieve this?
This is how I am fetching all distanceWalkingRunning samples from an HKWorkout:
func fetchDistanceSamples(for workout: HKWorkout, completion: @escaping ([HKQuantitySample]) -> Void) {
    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
        logger.warning("HealthKit is not available on this device.")
        return
    }
    
    let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: workout.startDate, end: workout.endDate, options: [.strictStartDate, .strictStartDate])
    
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in
        if let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            completion(samples.sorted(by: { $0.endDate < $1.endDate } ))
        } else {
            completion([])
        }
    }
    
    HKHealthStore.execute(query)
}


You are looking for HKQuantitySeriesSampleQuery. In other words, you don't "extract" them; you obtain them by query, similar to your let query.
